# Application doesn't reflect updated contents once deployed locally through App Engine Standard

Tags: google-app-engine

I have just started working on App Engine and during my first sample run only I faced this issue. I deployed the sample 'Hello App Engine' servlet code locally through Eclipse IDE. After hitting the localhost URL I was able to see the expected message 'Hello App Engine' as well.
Later I changed the message body to be displayed (Hi App Engine) and again deployed the code. Now, when I hit the localhost URL I don't see the updated message body. Instead it shows me the old message (Hello App Engine) only.
I tried refreshing my browser and manually setting the 'Run configuration' but nothing worked. Does anybody have any leads what could be the possible reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified you are executing the redeployment correctly?.

To make sure you are not failing in this step you should delete the application completely and redeploy it again